# Resource needed to manage cert.db7 files for AIX

Tags: firefox, aix, ldap, ssl

On AIX to get LDAP authentication working it has wanted to store the LDAP SSL certificate's trusted root in a cert.db7 file.  Mozilla stopped supporting it in NSS (Netscape Security Services) a while back.  Cognos (also from IBM) used to use cert.db7 but in the latest versions switched to cert.db8 which is easy to make just using Firefox.

Anyone have good resources for making a cert.db7 file?  Converters?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean `cert7.db`.

According to [mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/db_formats.html) it's not a fixed format.  But there are lots of results if you google for `cert7.db` or `edit cert7.db` or `create cert7.db` or `convert cert7.db` that should point you in the right direction.